# Spark Streaming - dynamic allocation do not remove executors in middle of windows interval

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, spark-streaming, dynamic-allocation

I have a spark streaming job with batch Interval of 10 minutes and slides/window of 1 hour, I have activated the dynamic allocation with Spark.

But executors get removed after 1 hours and not after each 10 min of Batch Interval, So I have to wait 1 hour to see executors removed (in case of no data to process).

Is there a way to tell spark to revise excecutors removal after each batch interval instead of Window interval ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check executor idle timeout property settings in job level or default config (spark-defaults.conf)

- spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout
- spark.dynamicAllocation.cachedExecutorIdleTimeout

Refer [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation) link for more details.

Comment: It solved my problem after setting :
spark.dynamicAllocation.cachedExecutorIdleTimeout = 60s

Thanks